# How to read and store names of all the columns from multiple sheets in excel using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 25 sheets in the excel file and I want the list of column names(top row/header) from each of the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify how you want the answers collected? Do you want all the column names from each sheet in the same list or dataframe?

**Assuming you want the results in one DataFrame:** I will assume you want to collect the results into one DataFrame where each row represents one sheet and each column represents one column name. The general idea is to loop through The pd.read_excel() method specifying a different sheet name each time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_sheets = 25
int_sheet_names = np.arange(0,n_sheets,1)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in int_sheet_names:
    sheet_i_col_names = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = i, header=None, nrows=1)
    df = df.append(sheet_i_col_names)
```

The resulting DataFrame can be further manipulated based on your specific requirements.

[Output from my example excel sheet, which only had 4 sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88ncM.png)

**Alternatively**, you can pass a list to the *sheet_names* argument. In this case, you are given a dictionary, which I find to be less useful. In this case, *int_sheet_names* must be a list and not a numpy array.

```
n_sheets = 25
int_sheet_names = list(range(0,n_sheets))
dict = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = int_sheet_names, head=None, nrows=1)
```

[Output as a dictionary when passing a list to *sheet_name* *kwarg*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhZQy.png)

Comment: Thanks. I modified this a bit. The sheet names are custom in my excel file, so I did it this way.


    xls = pd.ExcelFile('Desktop/Multiple.xlsx')
    int_sheet_names = xls.sheet_names
    df = pd.DataFrame()